# How for an app to change its taskbar hover text or snapped window title?

Tags: windows-11, taskbar, notification-area, title

What's the proper keyword for the line "how to change hover text tas..." in [this image](https://imgur.com/o2EYWKp)? For now let me temporarily call it `snapped window title` - SWT. At the same time, when we hover the mouse over some taskbar apps / tray icons / start menu, some texts will appear, which I'll refer to as `taskbar hover text` - THT. It looks like apps can change their SWT with ease (or Windows is good at capturing it) - for example, whenever I switch a tab in Firefox, the SWT changes, too.

I have an app that I want to display some changing content (based on the state of the app) in either the SWT or, preferably, THT, because the message could be a bit long. Is it possible to do that? And how? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The hovertext of icons in your taskbar work as follows:

If the app is not open, it will use the name of the app or shortcut.

For example, if you create a shorcut to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`, the shortcut automatically is called `Command Prompt`. If you pin this shorcut to your taskbar, the hovertext `Command Prompt` is shown when hovering.

If you now edit the shortcut and change the `Command Prompt` to `Hack this computer`, the hovertext will now automatically say `Hack this computer`.

But when you open the shortcut `Hack this computer` you'll see that it changes the hovertext back to `Command Prompt`.

The reason for this is because once you open a program, the hovertext changes to whatever the title of the windows app becomes. For Command Prompt, that changes to `Command Prompt`.

But in Command Prompt, you can use the command `title My New Title` to change the title of Command Prompt to `My New Title`. After you changed this, the hovertext has now changed to `My New Title`.

Every app has a windows title, but not every app shows this windows title anymore, which can make it confusing that it really just is the windows title that you see when hovering it in the taskbar.

So in order to change the hovertext, the windows title of that app must change. Not every app does this, but there are tools available that can change this on the fly. But it would be better to contact the developer and do a feature request for them to update the windows title bar. Its an easy fix for them.